# How can I tease Sonicwall ?

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, proxy

In my college, I can't use the web, because they use [Sonicwall network firewalls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SonicWall)

How can I tease it? For I use all websites in my college?

Please see the result when I access a website blocked

[image: here]

I already tried use non-proxy but it didn't worked.

Thanks!

Comment: They've blocked **Freeware/Software Downloads**? WTF, this is dumb!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If outgoing SSH works, you can use SSH tunneling to set up a SOCKS proxy which will effectively bypass the firewall. You will obviously need the following:

1. Make sure SonicWall doesn't block outgoing SSH connections (TCP port 22). If they do, and you have full control over the SSH server outside of this network (e.g. if you run one at home), try running it on a different port, or even on port 80 or 443.
2. Use ssh with the **-D8080** switch to log on to the remote SSH server. If the SSH server runs on a different port (e.g. 443) use **-p443** to specify the port. For example: `ssh -D8080 -p443 user@yourserver.example.com`
3. Keep the SSH session open, and configure your browser to use a SOCKS proxy on localhost, TCP port 8080 (should be the default setting).
4. Go to ipchicken.com or whatismyip.com to confirm that your browser is using your SSH tunnel/proxy.
5. Enjoy unrestricted Internet access.

I like this trick a lot, because it actually encrypts with SSH all traffic to/from your computer. Note, however, that some plugins, like Flash, will ignore your browser's proxy setting and will still try to connect directly. That means that sites using Flash video players may not work, however, browser-based HTML5 players should work.

Comment: my ssh is work and open when I use nmap localhost appear 22/tcp    open  ssh. But when I change my browser to use a SOCKS, after do this, not open anytihng website...

Comment: Did you run the `ssh -D8080 yourname@yoursshserver.com` command in the terminal before changing the SOCKS proxy settings? Remember that it's SSH that sets up the proxy. Can you go inside the SSH shell and run commands on your server? Remember: the SSH server needs to be outside of the firewall; you can't SSH to your own machine.

Comment: I access another pc but that port is not 8080 but 22. Or I have to change my own port in ssh from 22 to 8080?

Comment: Is possible to tease using openvpn?

Comment: Is possible to use this in all my pc, even just my firefox?